# Remove Git repository, but keep all files

Tags: linux, git

At some point during my adventures with Linux, I decided that it would be a good idea to put everything in my home directory into source control. I'm not asking whether that was a good idea or not -- I'm asking how to undo it.

The reason for removing the repository is that I recently installed Oh My Zsh, and I really like it. The rub is that my home directory has a big `git:(master)` stuck behind it, and I'm just not a huge fan of that.

[image]

So what I would like to do is remove the git repository itself, so that the `git:(master)` is no longer displayed, *without* deleting all of my files.

Comment: While the question itself is stated clearly, to me, it makes no sense at all to delete a repository to get rid of part of a shell prompt... something is wrong here, I think. Could it be a case of X-Y-problem? Of course, that does not affect the actual question here - but could discover the "real", underlying question of the OP, like maybe "How to disable the git prompt for certain repositorys only?"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just remove (or rename) the `.git` subdirectory. That subdirectory is the whole of the repository. This will not delete your files, but it *will* delete their history.

Additionally, there might be files like `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` that are not necessary anymore.

Make sure that all your files are present in the working tree before removing/renaming `.git`.

Answer (score 4):

Removing the directory `.git` in a repository removes the **history**, and keeps the files **currently checked out** - it **does not keep all files**.

*Warning: this may not be what you need!*

The history contains **earlier states** of files, files that **were removed** at some time, and **other branches**, containing similar, up to date files similar to the currently checked out, or **completely different** ones.

That means, in the general case, removing the `.git` affects files that where in the repository tree earlier, and files that currently - in the newest version - exist in other branches. **All these would be deleted too!**

*The answers proposing to just delete `.git` apply only in the simplest case,*
 where you only added files to the master branch since creating the repository, and master is checked out.

Answer (score 3):

Your repository resides in the .git directory, you can delete it easily. But if only the prompt disturbs you, it is enough to search where PROMPT gets new value in your environment and modify it to something else.

Comment: Simply removing the prompt was my first instinct. I found where the string is set, `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/git.zsh` at the very top, but I was unsure how to modify it. I may revisit this in the future.