# My entire folder with in-built program files is a working directory for git, it has been tracking all my files, I want to remove .git entirely

Tags: git, git-bash, .git-folder

I do not know to use git bash I ended up doing something and now it's been tracking all my files, what should I do to remove that entirely from my system?

The files that are being tracked:

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ3EO.png)]

I thought of using
rm -fr .git
But I am scared if it would delete files from my local system

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Git repository, but keep all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796285/remove-git-repository-but-keep-all-files)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm assuming everything is being push onto a Remote Repository. In that case used:

```
git remote remove origin
```